# Looping through json response and finding string

Tags: python, json

I'm getting a response from an api (put it at the bottom, it's quite lengthy)

Now I want to loop through the response and find a specific object using a value to a key in the object.

For example if I search for `United States` I want get everything from the object with `country_name: United States`

My code:

```py
import requests
r = requests.get(api_url)
response = r.json()
command = "United States"


for line in response['data']['stock']:
  if line['country_name'].lower() == command:
      print(line['country_name'] + " " + line['invite_total'])
```

This only checks if `command` is the same as the first object in the long chain fo all the objects

The response:

````
{
    "status": true,
    "data": {
        "message": "Stock request was successful",
        "exec_time": 0.005613088607788086,
        "stock": [
            {
                "iso_code": "DE",
                "country_name": "Germany",
                "invite_total": 0
            },
            {
                "iso_code": "US",
                "country_name": "United States",
                "invite_total": 4
            },
            {
                "iso_code": "NO",
                "country_name": "Norway",
                "invite_total": 0
            },
            {
                "iso_code": "AR",
                "country_name": "Argentina",
                "invite_total": 3
            },
            {
                "iso_code": "SK",
                "country_name": "Slovakia",
                "invite_total": 0
            },
            {
                "iso_code": "BR",
                "country_name": "Brazil",
                "invite_total": 2
            },
            {
                "iso_code": "CA",
                "country_name": "Canada",
                "invite_total": 0
            },
            {
                "iso_code": "AU",
                "country_name": "Australia",
                "invite_total": 0
            },
            {
                "iso_code": "TR",
                "country_name": "Turkey",
                "invite_total": 0
            },
            {
                "iso_code": "ID",
                "country_name": "Indonesia",
                "invite_total": 2
            },
            {
                "iso_code": "SE",
                "country_name": "Sweden",
                "invite_total": 0
            },
            {
                "iso_code": "EC",
                "country_name": "Ecuador",
                "invite_total": 0
            },
            {
                "iso_code": "DK",
                "country_name": "Denmark",
                "invite_total": 0
            },
            {
                "iso_code": "CH",
                "country_name": "Switzerland",
                "invite_total": 0
            },
            {
                "iso_code": "GB",
                "country_name": "United Kingdom",
                "invite_total": 0
            },
            {
                "iso_code": "CL",
                "country_name": "Chile",
                "invite_total": 0
            },
            {
                "iso_code": "CZ",
                "country_name": "Czech Republic",
                "invite_total": 0
            },
            {
                "iso_code": "MX",
                "country_name": "Mexico",
                "invite_total": 0
            },
            {
                "iso_code": "NL",
                "country_name": "Netherlands",
                "invite_total": 0
            },
            {
                "iso_code": "FR",
                "country_name": "France",
                "invite_total": 0
            },
            {
                "iso_code": "BE",
                "country_name": "Belgium",
                "invite_total": 0
            },
            {
                "iso_code": "ES",
                "country_name": "Spain",
                "invite_total": 0
            },
            {
                "iso_code": "PH",
                "country_name": "Philippines",
                "invite_total": 0
            },
            {
                "iso_code": "TW",
                "country_name": "Taiwan",
                "invite_total": 0
            },
            {
                "iso_code": "SV",
                "country_name": "El Salvador",
                "invite_total": 0
            },
            {
                "iso_code": "IS",
                "country_name": "Iceland",
                "invite_total": 0
            },
            {
                "iso_code": "IT",
                "country_name": "Italy",
                "invite_total": 0
            },
            {
                "iso_code": "SG",
                "country_name": "Singapore",
                "invite_total": 0
            },
            {
                "iso_code": "NZ",
                "country_name": "New Zealand",
                "invite_total": 0
            },
            {
                "iso_code": "CO",
                "country_name": "Colombia",
                "invite_total": 0
            },
            {
                "iso_code": "PE",
                "country_name": "Peru",
                "invite_total": 0
            },
            {
                "iso_code": "AE",
                "country_name": "United Arab Emirates",
                "invite_total": 0
            },
            {
                "iso_code": "HN",
                "country_name": "Honduras",
                "invite_total": 0
            },
            {
                "iso_code": "UY",
                "country_name": "Uruguay",
                "invite_total": 10
            },
            {
                "iso_code": "SA",
                "country_name": "Saudi Arabia",
                "invite_total": 0
            },
            {
                "iso_code": "LU",
                "country_name": "Luxembourg",
                "invite_total": 0
            },
            {
                "iso_code": "IE",
                "country_name": "Ireland",
                "invite_total": 0
            },
            {
                "iso_code": "IN",
                "country_name": "India",
                "invite_total": 0
            },
            {
                "iso_code": "DO",
                "country_name": "Dominican Republic",
                "invite_total": 0
            },
            {
                "iso_code": "MY",
                "country_name": "Malaysia",
                "invite_total": 0
            }
        ]
    }
}```
````

Comment: What exactly is the issue here? The response doesn't just show values with the command specified?

Comment: what is the object you are talking about? The stock dictionary?

Comment: When I run it it just returns the values from the first object `Germany` ti doesn't actually search through them